# How to pass gitlab-ci variables to script for setting up ssh-keys to a server

Tags: gitlab, docker-compose, docker-machine, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to pass gitlab-ci variables to a script on a docker gitlab-ci-runner. The reason for wanting to do this is to setup Continuous Delivery using docker-compose. I have SERVER_USER and SERVER_PASS setup in a project on gitlab.

I tried passing the variables the script by using

```
export SUSER = $SERVER_USER
export SPASS = SERVER_PASS
chmod +x script && ./script


script

#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh-copy-id $SUSER
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
send "yes\n"
expect "password:"
send "$SPASS\n"
expect eof
```

But I'm getting unknown variable SUSER. How should I go about it.